# How to add Arrows in Scroll Bar (Left - Right)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to add arrows on the left and right from the scroll bar as a second navigation tool.

The scroll bar now is mobile friendly and scrolling with finger

Has any idea how to take it

CSS

```
<style>

a
{
  color: #252525;
  text-decoration-line: none;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  transition-duration: 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 20ms;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
}

.window {
    margin-top: 12px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    /* fixes scrolling in IE */
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; 
      margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}


.ie8 .window 
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0; 
}


.slider-frame-wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.slider-frame {
  overflow: visible;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.ie8 .slider-frame { 

  background-color: #ececec;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position-x: 0%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  background-size: auto auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.slider-panel {
    max-width: 270px; /* width of each individual items */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 7px;
    white-space: normal;
     border-right-width: 3px;
  border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: black;
    padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float: none;

}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>

               <div class="well window">
                <div class="slider-frame-wrapper">    
                 <ul class="slider-frame">

<li class="slider-panel"><h2><a  title="iPhone" href="#/apple-    c-19.html">iPhone</a></h2></li>

<li class="slider-panel"><h2>
<a title="Samsung" href="#/samsung-c-21.html">Samsung</a></h2>
</li>
<li class="slider-panel"><h2>
<a title="LG" href="#/lg-c-23.html">LG</a></h2>
</li>
<li class="slider-panel"><h2>
<a title="Huawei" href="#/huawei-c-31.html">Huawei</a></h2>
</li>
<li class="slider-panel"><h2>
<a title="Sony" href="#/sony-c-24.html">Sony</a></h2>
</li>
 </ul>      
  </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

set .window{ overflow-x: visible; } in your CSS. Now you can pan your entire HTML with fingerstrokes.

For some reason, StackOverflow insists that my answer be longer, or it won't let me place it.